# Match string and put all results in a list in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am going to match something from a string, and I want to put all the matched strings into a list; how would I do that?

Right now I am using this

```
myStr = 'one two one three'
match = re.match(r'one', myStr)
```

But when I print the content of variable `match` using `print m.group()`, it only displays the first occurrence. I want to get all the occurrences and then put all those values into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'one', 'one two one three')
['one', 'one']
```